# How can a linq query be converted to JavaScript array containing only values?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a JavaScript grid library (it creates a table on the page) that accepts a JavaScript array as input, for rendering in the grid.  I'm not certain, however, how to convert a Linq-to-SQL query (against a SQL Server database) to a JavaScript array containing only values.

I tried this, but it included the table column names in the JSON key (and I don't want JSON anyway, I want a JavaScript string array, unless this can be converted to an array?):

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query)
```

Example of the format I need to produce:

```
[1,2,3],[4,5,6]
```

---

**Environment: .NET Core 3.1**

edit: Here is a sample of what I've currently got, this returns the less than desirable JSON (due to the query results being so large, having a JSON key for very element is going to literally double the size of the query):

**Devices Table**

```
ID   Name
1    iPhone7
2    iPhone8
3    iPhone9
```

**Needed Array (Note: no column names)**

```
[1, "iPhone7"],[2, "iPhone8"],[3, "iPhone9"]
```

**Current C# code in the controller method (returns undesirable key for every element currently)**

```
var query = db.Devices;
var formattedResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query);
return Ok(formattedResult);
```

Comment: convert a query? or convert results of a query? Also are you trying to do this in the view?

Comment: @JerdineSabio Convert the results of a query to JavaScript array.  And I would prefer to do this sever-side at Controller level versus having the View do it.  Need to convert the results of the linq query to something JavaScript will accept as a JavaScript array (format in post).  Thanks!

Comment: Additional details: JavaScript is calling this Controller method via an ajax call, so the results given from the Controller method (example:   return Ok(formattedResults) ) need to work as an array for JavaScript.  Thanks!

Comment: I think JSON is what you need here. 1) We send json as result to your ajax call, 2) in the success callback of your ajax, we convert the json result to your js array, 3) you then use the js array.

Comment: please include the json in the question you are trying to convert, you could do `console.log(result)`

Comment: @JerdineSabio The concern with returning JSON is that the response is going to be very large (100k+ rows) and if the key is included for each JSON element, that will literally double the size of the response.  The beauty of returning just a JavaScript string array is that it only will contain the values.

Comment: I see, will you include the results object in the question-- and which properties you want to be included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, you could do this:

```
var query = db.Devices.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(d => new object[]{d.ID, d.Name});
var formattedResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query);
return Ok(formattedResult);
```

But then the code on the other end of your request is going to have to translate all those arrays back into objects.

It's rarely worthwhile to complicate your model like this in order to optimize the size of your network traffic. If you're pulling enough items over the wire to make this a performance issue, you're likely to encounter a variety of other performance issues. I would first consider other options, like implementing paging.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try

```
var query = db.Devices.ToList(); 
var array = JArray.FromObject(query);
return Ok(formattedResult)
```

Comment: Where did `ids` come from?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).